# Calculating the matrix

Tags: matrices

I need some hint towards calculating $$e^{iAx}Be^{-iAx}$$ Given that $[A,B]=B$

I have been manipulating this (by expansion) for quite a while, and am wondering if there is any clever way to approach this problem. In the expansion, just the first order terms seem to suggest a solution like $e^{i Bx}$ but higher order terms mess it up. Besides the brute force, the only thing I have seen here is that if  $X=e^{iAx}Be^{-iAx}$ then $[A,X] = X$. So X might be B times some factor, though that is not a guarantee.  Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: hmm... going over wikipeidia, there's another method.. to use $ e^{A}Be^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+\frac{1}{3!}[A,[A,[A,B]]]+\cdots $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: what is $\frac{d}{dx} e^{iAx}Be^{-iAx}$?